# how do I redirect output of echo "!#/bin/bash" into another SH file using vi editor

Tags: shell-script, vi

basically I am creating another SH file inside a SH file using vi editor and echo commands.
here is the content of original SH file-

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "#!/bin/bash" > f1.sh
echo "echo "hello"" > f1.sh
```

f1 is the SH file I want to  write into using echo commands
but upon running the original file
f1 file does not get #!bin/bash written into it
it only has the echo "hello" command.
I have tried writing the echo HASHBANG command as
echo \#\!/bin/bash
but that is not working as well.
so how do u write #!bin/bash into another SH file using echo commands in vi editor?

Comment: `>` truncates the output file, `>>` appends to it. You're truncating the file on each echo, so only the text output by the last echo stays there. Also note that `"echo "hello""` is the same as `"echo "hello`, or `"echo hello"`, the "inner" quotes won't be there in the output. Try something like `echo 'echo "hello"'`. Or use a here-doc.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks I got it

Answer (score 1):

Use a here-document instead:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cat >f1.sh <<'SCRIPT_END'
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
SCRIPT_END
```

This passes the script as it is, without the shell interfering in anything, to `cat`, which redirects it to the file `f1.sh`.

There are many issues wih your code, but the issue related to redirection is that you truncate (empty) the `f1.sh` file each time you use `>`  to redirect to it.  This means that the second `echo` in your code overwrites the data written to the file by he first `echo`.

Also, the quoting on the second line with `echo` does not make sense.

The Vi editor does not have anything to do with this.